# I have 2 columns x and y and want output if x>y, print True than false

Tags: python

I have 2 columns x and y and want output if x>y, print True than false

```
    x   y   x>y
0   1  12  False
1   5  11  False
2   7   1   True
3   8   2   True
4   9   5   True
5  10  20  False
6  11  13  False
```

Comment: What format and form is your data in?  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare the colums:

```
df['x>y'] = df['x'] > df['y']
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
'y':[12, 11, 1, 2, 5, 20, 13],})

df['x>y'] = df['x'] > df['y']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    x   y    x>y
0   1  12  False
1   5  11  False
2   7   1   True
3   8   2   True
4   9   5   True
5  10  20  False
6  11  13  False
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help